# How to Handle Select Input Async React Js? Material UI: You have provided an out-of-range value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning CRUD with React Js, MERN STACK.

I'm having a problem working on the update feature, Material UI says:

1. "You have provided an out-of-range value **server1** for the select (name = "server") component. ".
2. You have provided an out-of-range value **profile1** for the select (name =" profile ")

I suspect, this is because the api calls **/server/** and **/profile/** have been loaded late and are displaying an **"out-of-range**" warning.

this is the code I use.

```
...

const params = useParams();
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const [serverList, setServerList] = useState([]);
const [profileList, setProfileList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`/user/id/${params.userId}`).then((result) => {
    setUser(result.data.data);
  });
}, [params.userId]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/server/").then((result) => {
    setServerList(result.data.data);
  });
  axios.get("/profile/").then((result) => {
    setProfileList(result.data.data);
  });
}, []);


return(

...

<FormControl variant="outlined" required fullWidth>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="server">Server</InputLabel>
  <Select
    name="server"
    label="Server"
    labelId="server"
    id="server"
    value={user.server || ""}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
  >
    <MenuItem value="all">All</MenuItem>
    {serverList.map((server) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={server[".id"]}
        value={server.name}
      >
        {server.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>

// .... select input profile is similar

...

)
```

This took up quite a lot of my time, I hope to get an answer here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It hard to debug without real example, maybe you can provide example of data that you set in `setServerList` and `setUser`, for example `user.server` can be object, but all your options `server.name` are strings and in this case you can get "out-of-range value" error.